# How to add pagination for elastic search

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, pagination

I am using elastic search as searching tool in my application...

I am having 9 records in my db.

My page size is 5.

So first time it will give me 5 records which is working fine by my code...

Now second time when I scroll it should give me 4 records and then scrolling should give me 0 records.

{

```
   "from" : 0, "size" : size,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

I am using above code for query.

using above code the data is not coming proper as first time it is giving me 5 records, 2nd time also it is giving me 5 records then it will reduce count as 4,3,2.

Kindly help me to allow pagination in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you specify the second time as `from` value? 
Can you post what you request in the second query call.

tip: It should be `from: 5` and not `from: 1`. It is not a page counter but a record counter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass

```
1st time
"from" : 0,
"size" : 5


2nd time 
"from" : 5,
"size" : 5
```

Your query will be looking like

```
{
  "query": {
    ... Your elasticsearch query
  },
  "_source": [
    .... Columns To retrieve
  ],
  "sort": [
    .... Sorting information
  ],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5
}
```

This is for elasticsearch `2.3`

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply..
though i change "from" value i am getting first five records only